# Difference between \begin{theorem}...\end{theorem} and {\theorem ...}

Tags: environments, theorems

I see that both attempts to display a theorem in the following code generates similar output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
\( (a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2 \)
\end{theorem}

{
\theorem
\( (a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2 \)
}
\end{document}
```

I want to know what the difference between `\begin{theorem}...\end{theorem}` and `{\theorem ...}` is.

Comment: Are you familiar with Plain TeX and LaTeX differences?

Comment: @percusse No, I work only with LaTeX. Is `\begin{theorem}...\end{theorem}` LaTeX way of writing a theorem while `{\theorem ...}` TeX way of writing a theorem?

Comment: In a nutshell yes, but I'm not entitled to give a comprehensive answer. This is also the root of the confusion about `\center,\centering` and `\begin{center}...\end{center}`. See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables

Comment: a misguided user just sent a bug report to the latex bugs site saying that the heading font for all theorems after using `\remark{...}` was changed to italic.  (he didn't use braces to isolate the theorem input.)  *all* latex documentation says that theorems are to be input as environments, not commands, so clearly, the instructions weren't being followed.  egreg's answer gives good reasons why one should follow the instructions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assume `foo` is some environment; with

```
\begin{foo}
```

LaTeX does some bookkeping, opens a group and expands the macro

```
\foo
```

With

```
\end{foo}
```

some check are performed, `\endfoo` is expanded and the group is closed.

In the case of `theorem`, we can test

```
\show\theorem
\show\endtheorem
```

which gives

```
> \theorem=macro:
->\@thm {\let \thm@swap \@gobble \th@plain }{theorem}{Theorem}.

> \endtheorem=macro:
->\endtrivlist \@endpefalse .
```

It may seem that `\endtheorem` is no big deal; but let's see what `\endtrivlist` means:

```
> \endtrivlist=macro:
->\if@inlabel \leavevmode \global \@inlabelfalse \fi \if@newlist
\@noitemerr \global \@newlistfalse \fi \ifhmode \unskip \par \else 
\@inmatherr {\end {\@currenvir }}\fi \if@noparlist \else \ifdim
\lastskip >\z@ \@tempskipa \lastskip \vskip -\lastskip \advance
\@tempskipa \parskip \advance \@tempskipa -\@outerparskip \vskip
\@tempskipa \fi \@endparenv \fi .
```

So you're missing *several* things if you omit `\end{theorem}`.

Perhaps, in the case of `theorem` not much is missed, but only getting "similar" output doesn't guarantee that, maybe some pages later, something goes awry. The most striking aspect in the particular case is that the vertical spacing after the statement will be wrong, even if you leave an empty line after the closing brace.

This practice is definitely *not* recommendable: some environments do the bulk  of their work exactly at `\end...`; others do almost nothing at that stage. One should know in depth what every environment does.

Finally, the `{\theorem ...}` syntax is clumsy.

Comment: Nice! Where should I type `\show\theorem\show\endtheorem` to see that lines?

Comment: @Sigur Just add them to your document and compile it from the command line. You can get a "printed" version good for non interactive runs with `{\ttfamily\meaning\theorem}`.

Comment: It's interesting to note that `\theorem` survives *without* `\endtheorem`. Yes you "missing *several* things" but there's no compile error. This is because there's no grouping between the two commands; something inherent when using the `\begin{theorem}`...`\end{theorem}` pair.

Comment: @Sigur: Review the `.log` file after the run, since `\show` flushes its contents there.

Comment: @Werner No compile error doesn't mean that the output is correct.

Answer (score 12):

As soon as you add some material after both constructs you'll see the difference; `\end{theorem}` uses `\endtrivlist` which internally uses `\par`, effectively ending a paragraph; in the second construct there's no paragraph ending:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
\( (a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2 \)
\end{theorem}
aaa

{
\theorem
\( (a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2 \)
}
aaa
\end{document}
```

[image]